# LDD Update Date?

Tags: software, ldd

I was wondering the other day - When was LDD last updated and when, if ever, are they (TLG) planning to do another piece update?

Comment: @NathanStohlmann No, I was just wondering if there was going to be an update and, if so, what it would contain.

Comment: The link does answer the question. At the end of the accepted answer is says, "LDD is no longer supported by TLG". So the answer to "when are TLG planning to do an update" is "never".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In January of 2016 the LEGO Group officially [announced through the Ambassador's Forum that Lego Digital Designer (LDD) had been defunded and would not be receiving any more updates](https://www.brothers-brick.com/2016/01/21/lego-digital-designer-officially-defunded-and-unsupported-news/). In the following year there were 2 more updates, however in at least one of those updates parts were actually removed from the library.

The software is still available for download from the LEGO site and the support information has never been updated with the official announcement but follow-ups with the company have consistently received the same answer as the announcement in January 2016.

It should also be noted that [in late 2019 The LEGO Group acquired BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/community/newsview.page?msgid=1166622) which produces the Stud.io modelling software. At the time of the acquisition, the [following Frequently Asked Question was published](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/announcement/lego_bl_faq.page) (Under "Acquisition"):

> **7. What about Studio and LEGO Digital Designer (LDD) – what will happen with the two digital building experiences since they’re quite similar?**
> The LEGO Group is planning to support and evolve Studio and will review opportunities for both services following the closing of the deal.

Comment: @zhaph-ben-duguid Thanks for that correction!

Comment: TLG has announced that after 2022-01-31 the LDD website will be full removed and direct downloads from LEGO will no longer be available, nor will there ever be any more official updates to the software or the parts database. https://www.brothers-brick.com/2022/01/12/lego-fully-discontinuing-lego-digital-designer-in-favor-of-bricklink-studio/